# How to load font variants from the same family in Pyglet?

Tags: python, fonts, pyglet

I would like to display multiple text labels with various fonts in Pyglet. In this case I am using the "Ubuntu" font, in bold and other times italic. In this case I have `Ubuntu-B.ttf` and `Ubuntu-BI.ttf` as font files.

As directed by the [instructions](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/loading_custom_fonts.html), I am loading the fonts with:

```
pyglet.font.add_file(font_filename)
```

Then using it with its *face name* (I am hard-coding "Ubuntu" because I can't see a way to get it from the font file):

```
label = pyglet.text.Label(text="Hello", font_name="Ubuntu", font_size=16)
```

Unfortunately the Pyglet font system seems to only register the first font with that face name `Ubuntu`, and it uses that for all instances of the font, italic or otherwise.

So if I load `Ubuntu-BI.ttf` first, then all uses of `Ubuntu` are italic. If I load `Ubuntu-B.ttf` first, then all uses are non-italic bold, even if I load the italic font at a later stage.

I can't see an obvious way to clear or remove a loaded font at run-time. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: One observation is that changing the font size for, say, the italic cases causes the other cases to render with the correct font. Maybe there's a font-cache issue going on here?

Comment: Alternatively maybe there's an undocumented way to adjust the associated face name for each font file loaded through `pyglet.font.add_file()`?

Answer (score 4):

I have found my own solution. There is an undocumented class called `pyglet.font.ttf.TruetypeInfo` that can be used to obtain the correct *face name* for a particular font file. This allows me to use the correct face name when attempting to use the different fonts (rather than relying on Pyglet to choose the best option based on an incomplete face name). So I can now directly use the fonts I require:

```
def load_font(path):
    # load external font from file
    p = TruetypeInfo(path)
    name = p.get_name("name")
    p.close()
    font.add_file(path)
    print("Loaded font " + name + " from " + path)
```

Reference [pyglet-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pyglet-users/MDEU_fyJkkA) thread.

Comment: Just to note that the class is actually  `pyglet.font.ttf.TruetypeInfo`, at least in 2015

Comment: @Jonathan yes, you are quite correct, thank you. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building on meowsqueak's answer, you might want to use `get_name('family')` instead of `get_name('name')`. To be more specific, in my case I had a single .ttf file that only contained the Bold version. Using

```
    p = pyglet.font.ttf.TruetypeInfo(path)
    print p.get_name('name')
    print p.get_name('family')
```

produced

```
Orbitron Bold
Orbitron
```

pyglet didn't pick up the font with

```
pyglet.text.Label(text="Text", font_name='Orbitron Bold')
```

but

```
pyglet.text.Label(text="Text", font_name='Orbitron', bold=True,
```

worked.